# Want to update a QtableWidget within a QThread

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm starting a project called Nice System Monitor aiming to monitor processes on Linux, and I'm using C++ and Qt with QtCreator.

I've started making a QThread with a function called to fill a QTableWidget repeatedly but the table doesn't update properly even if I delete each row before fulling it up again.

I'm quite new to Qt and inspired myself of different sources on the Internet.

Here's the code of the QThread :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "renderprocesstablethread.h"
#include <proc/readproc.h>
#include <proc/procps.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"
using namespace std;


RenderProcessTableThread::RenderProcessTableThread(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    restart = false;
    abort = false;
}

RenderProcessTableThread::~RenderProcessTableThread()
{
    mutex.lock();
    abort = true;
    condition.wakeOne();
    mutex.unlock();

    wait();
}

bool RenderProcessTableThread::isNum(char *s) {
    int i = 0,  flag;

    while(s[i]){
            //if there is a letter in a string then string is not a number
        if(isalpha(s[i]) || s[i] == '.'){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        else flag = 1;
        i++;
        }
    if (flag == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

string RenderProcessTableThread::convertDouble(double value) {
  std::ostringstream o;
  if (!(o << value))
    return "";
  return o.str();
}

string RenderProcessTableThread::convertInt(int value) {
  std::ostringstream o;
  if (!(o << value))
    return "";
  return o.str();
}



void RenderProcessTableThread::run()
{
    forever {
        mutex.lock();
        mutex.unlock();
        fillProcessTable();
        sleep(1000);
        //cout << "ça marche" << endl;
    }
    mutex.lock();
    if (!restart)
        condition.wait(&mutex);
    restart = false;
    mutex.unlock();

}


void RenderProcessTableThread::setLocalMainWindow(MainWindow& w)
{
    localMainWindow = &w;
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus = localMainWindow->findChild<QTableWidget*>("tableWidgetProcessus");
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setColumnCount(11);
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setColumnWidth(10,508);
    QFont fnt;
    fnt.setPointSize(10);
    fnt.setFamily("Arial");
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setFont(fnt);
    QStringList labels;
    labels << "user" << "pid" << "cpu" << "nice" << "vsz" << "rss" << "tty" << "stat" << "start" << "time" << "cmd";
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
}


void RenderProcessTableThread::fillProcessTable() {

    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

    if (!isRunning()) {
        start(LowPriority);
    } else {
        restart = true;
        condition.wakeOne();
    }

    PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLUSR | PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLSTAT | PROC_FILLSTATUS | PROC_FILLARG);
    proc_t proc_info;

    memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));

    int totalRow = ui_tableWidgetProcessus->rowCount();
    for ( int i = 0; i < totalRow ; ++i )
    {
           ui_tableWidgetProcessus->removeRow(i);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {
      cout << proc_info.fuser << proc_info.tid << proc_info.cmd << proc_info.resident << proc_info.utime << proc_info.stime << endl;
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setRowCount(i+1);
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString(proc_info.fuser),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.tid).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,2,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.pcpu).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,3,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.nice).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,4,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.vm_size).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,5,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.rss).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,6,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.tty).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,7,new QTableWidgetItem(QString(proc_info.state),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,8,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.start_time).c_str()),0));
      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,9,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.stime).c_str()),0));

      //cout << "proc_info.tid : " << proc_info.tid << endl;
      //cout << "proc_info.cmdline : " << proc_info.cmdline << endl;

      string text;
      if (proc_info.cmdline != 0) {
        vector<string> v(proc_info.cmdline, proc_info.cmdline + sizeof(proc_info.cmdline) / sizeof(string));
        text = v[0];
      }
      else {
        vector<string> v;
        v.push_back(proc_info.cmd);
        text = v[0];
      }
      //string text = char_to_string(proc_info.cmdline);

      ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(i,10,new QTableWidgetItem(QString((char*)text.c_str()),0));
      i++;
    }

    closeproc(proc);

}
```

Are they better ways of doing this ?

Thanks

Patrick

Comment: It doesn't clear from you post, what you expected to see and what was the result, and it is impossible to try to compile and test. Either expand your text or post whole source code.

Comment: you can find the complete sources at https://sourceforge.net/projects/nicesystemmonitor/ sorry it wasn't clear enough to you. I now have solved this problem and I'm moving the project forward. Thanks for trying  to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something for Qt's [Signal and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).
In your case the the thread emits the signal and a slot in your window will be called.

So in your RenderProcessTableThread.h define a signal

```
signals:
void newValues(const QString &data);
```

And in your mainwindow.h

```
public slots:
void showNewValues(const QString &data);
```

add the data to your table in this slot.
Then you have to connect them (e. g. in the constructor of your mainwindow after the creation of the thread)

```
connect(yourThread, SIGNAL(newValues(QString)), this, SLOT(showNewValues(QString)));
```

Whenever you want to show new data, emit the signal (e. g. somewhere in your `fillProcessTable()` function):

```
emit newValues(yourValues);
```

Qt does the connection between the threads for you.

Comment: Thanks Milania, I did something almost the way you said with signals and slots and it works fine, there were also a few glitches I corrected. The project is on sourceforge.net now at https://sourceforge.net/projects/nicesystemmonitor/ if you wish to see any more.